# Can I retarget a prebuilt ARM binary (static library)?

Tags: android, c, arm, newlib, eabi

I have a static library (.a) built to run directly on an ARM Cortex-M0+ (arm-none-eabi).  Is it possible to modify it or my toolchain somehow so that I can use the library on a Cortex-A7 running android (arm-linux-androideabi)?  I don't have access to the source it was built from.

The library does not interact with the hardware peripherals.
It was originally built with the Freescale ARM compiler; I'm using gcc.

When I tried to link it, I got

```
error: conflicting architecture profiles M/A
warning: {the file} uses variable-size enums yet the output is to use 32-bit enums; use of enum values across objects may fail
warning: cannot scan executable section {some number} of {the file} for Cortex-A8 erratum because it has no mapping symbols.
```

repeated a couple times for each object file in the library.

Comment: Depends what it is and what it does. At the basic level, yes, the code itself is binary-compatible, but if it contains privileged instructions (e.g. masking interrupts), peripheral accesses, hard-coded addresses or anything else you're liable to find in microcontroller code then it's not going to fly. It's also perhaps notable that the ARMv6-M ISA is a _very_ limited subset of what's available in ARMv7-A, so any code that is sufficiently boring to be able to run unmodified in an Android app is going to be comparatively horribly inefficient. More details of exactly what and why would help...

Comment: I wouldnt use the word horribly.  I would argue 10-20% slower than ARM and a little better than that against thumb2 extensions.  You gain a little on that with fetching, so in either case you may gain a little more on that 10-20%.